# R: how to fill in missing value with another dataset effeciently?

Tags: r, dplyr

Two input datasets:

```
A <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3), value = rep(NA, 3))
A 
     id value
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     1    NA
2     2    NA
3     3    NA

B <- data.frame(id = c(3, 2), value = c(3, 2))
B
  id value
1  3     3
2  2     2
```

After adding in available value in B to A, it's expected to have:

```
A 
     id value
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     1    NA
2     2    2
3     3    3
```

It can be achieved with following for loop. However, for-loop is in general very slow. How to do it more efficiently?

```
for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
  item <- A[i,]
  print(item)
  if(is.na(item$value) && (item$id %in% B$id)){
    A[i, "value"] <- B[B$id == item$id,]$value
  }
}
```

Join can solve this problem. but requiring a rule to resolve the conflict.

Comment: @nrussell, this needs B to overwrite A. which type of join does it belong to?

Comment: Left join then coalesce --`left_join(A, B, by = "id") %>% mutate(value = coalesce(value.x, value.y)) %>% select(id, value)`.

Comment: thanks. that is the answer.

Comment: Here is a base R method with `match`: `A$value[A$id %in% B$id] <-  B$value[match(A$id, B$id)[!is.na(match(A$id, B$id))]]` that works with the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join (`dplyr`):

```
library(dplyr)

A <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3), value = rep(NA, 3))
B <- data.frame(id = c(3, 2), value = c(3, 2))

A %>% left_join(B, by='id') %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value.x),value.y,value.x))
```

see comment of your question to learn what joining data is all about.

Comment: thanks. mutate works well with join for this case.

Comment: The `ifelse(is.na(value.x),value.y,value.x)` can also be achieved by `coalesce(value.x, value.y)`.